# Merge iCloud and core data db

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios5, icloud

I have an app which use core data and iCloud. In that i need to check if iCloud available or not, if iCloud is not present user can continue without iCloud. and he/she can do all operation, But suppose next time he/she run that application and iCloud is enable that time at that time i have to merge iCloud data with my local data. How i can achieve this, please help me in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WWDC 2012 Session 227 - Using iCloud with Core Data** specifically deals with your question. I absolutely recommend you watch it and update your post with any detailed questions that remain.